# How to handle bundle item's seo in eCommerce

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, magento

I have checked [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/how-to-handle-seo-for-pages-with-similar-textual-content) and similar to this. Almost all of them suggest to have canonical.

But I still find my case is little different than this.

I have magento based eCommerce site. And I have got some simple products and bundle products. Bundle products are the combination of these simple items, however bundle item has unique url.

**The Problem**

The main issue is with the content. Lets say I have

1. Simple products as "Simple product A, Simple product B"
2. Bundle product (made of "Simple product A and Simple product B)

Now, while creating bundle product, I cannot have completely unique content since this has to display content of "Simple product A and Simple product B" both, so that customer know what exactly they are looking at.

By doing this, robots are considering either simple product or this bundle product as duplicate.

If I have canonical in bundle item then, it will be missed by robots. I want robots to visit my bundle url and index them.

**Question**

How can I tackle this situation?

Comment: It should be noted that duplicate content is expected on most e-commerce sites as 9/10 of these sites use pre-written descriptions from manufactures. [Google no longer punishes duplicate content](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/duplicate-content-problems/#duplicate-content-seo-best-practice) the same way it did several years back. Google looks for positive signals, by adding reviews to the products these will help diversify the content and give positive signals. Google will not punish the site in the mean time waiting for reviews, its extremely hard to get punished nowadays.

Comment: This is some relief...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to explain why these three, or however many, products work well together and the reasoning behind them being bundled together. I'd suggest linking to each of these pages in your product description or an area that goes over included products. Find a writer who is creative, and is able to accomplish this for you. You don't necessarily need to explain each product in the bundle on that page. I would consider the bundle page description a chance to market your up-sell. Why should they get all of these products, and not just one individually? Whats the benefit of me buying all three products at the same time? There's always room for unique content.

Maybe explain what kind of products these are so we can see if there are any opportunities available for you to take advantage of.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please have a look these two products which are bundle items: https://www.digitalcinema.com.au/epson-eh-tw5300-projector-marantz-nr1506-receiver-jamo-s426hcs5-speaker-system-and-elegance-screen-complete-home-theatre-package.html and https://www.digitalcinema.com.au/epson-eh-tw5300-projector-complete-home-theatre-package.html